# how to use react native redux in react navigation

Tags: react-native, redux

I am using redux persist with asyncstorage save items in a bookmarks list. The items are in a flatlist and when I click on one item, it navigates me to another screen. I would like to implement the functional bookmark in the header of that screen.

When I tried doing this, and clicked the bookmark in the header, and go back to the bookmarks, it just shows a blank card. It looks like it is not updating the state properly. How can I fix this?

**StackNavigator.tsx**

```
const MainStackNavigator = () => {

  const { books, bookmarks } = useAppSelector((state) => state.booksReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchBooks = () => dispatch(getBooks());
  const addToBookmarkList = (book) => dispatch(addBookmark(book));
  const removeFromBookmarkList = (book) => dispatch(removeBookmark(book));

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchBooks();
  }, []);

  const handleAddBookmark = (book) => {
    addToBookmarkList(book);
  };

  const handleRemoveBookmark = (book) => {
    removeFromBookmarkList(book);
  };

  const handleSwapBookmark = (book) => {
    removeFromBookmarkList(book);
  };

  const RenderItem = () => {

    const ifExists = (book) => {
      if (bookmarks.filter((item) => item.id === book.id).length > 0) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    };
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          ifExists(i) ? handleRemoveBookmark(i) : handleAddBookmark(i)
        }
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          padding: 2,
          backgroundColor: ifExists(i) ? "#F96D41" : "#2D3038",
          borderRadius: 20,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
        }}
      >
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          color={ifExists(i) ? "white" : "#64676D"}
          size={24}
          name={ifExists(i) ? "bookmark-outline" : "bookmark"}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen
          name="BookmarksScreen"
          component={BookmarksScreen}
          options={{
            title: "Search",
            statusBarColor: isDarkMode ? "white" : "black",
            headerLargeTitle: true,
            headerTranslucent: true,
            headerLargeTitleHideShadow: true,
          }}
        />
        <AppStack.Screen
          name="Screen2"
          component={Screen2}
          options={({ route }) => ({
            headerLargeTitle: false,
            title: route.params.name,
            headerTranslucent: true,
            headerRight: () => <RenderItem item={route.params.name} />,
          })}
        />
      </AppStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**actions.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

import { BASE_URL } from "../config";

// Define action types
export const GET_BOOKS = "GET_BOOKS";
export const ADD_TO_BOOKMARK_LIST = "ADD_TO_BOOKMARK_LIST";
export const REMOVE_FROM_BOOKMARK_LIST = "REMOVE_FROM_BOOKMARK_LIST";
export const SWAP_IN_BOOKMARK_LIST = "SWAP_IN_BOOKMARK_LIST";

export const getBooks = () => {
  try {
    return async (dispatch) => {
      const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`);
      if (response.data) {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_BOOKS,
          payload: response.data,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Unable to fetch data from the API BASE URL!");
      }
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const addBookmark = (book) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TO_BOOKMARK_LIST,
    payload: book,
  });
};

export const removeBookmark = (book) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: REMOVE_FROM_BOOKMARK_LIST,
    payload: book,
  });
};
```

**hooks.ts**

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from "./store";
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

**reducers.ts**

```
import {
  GET_BOOKS,
  ADD_TO_BOOKMARK_LIST,
  REMOVE_FROM_BOOKMARK_LIST,
} from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  books: [],
  bookmarks: [],
};

function booksReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_BOOKS:
      return { ...state, books: action.payload };
    case ADD_TO_BOOKMARK_LIST:
      return { ...state, bookmarks: [...state.bookmarks, action.payload] };
    case REMOVE_FROM_BOOKMARK_LIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        bookmarks: state.bookmarks.filter(
          (book) => book.id !== action.payload.id
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default booksReducer;
```

**store.ts**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

import booksReducer from "./reducers";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ["bookmarks"],
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  booksReducer: persistReducer(persistConfig, booksReducer),
});

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

**BookmarksScreen.tsx**

```
const BookmarksScreen = () => {
return (
    <View>
         <FlatList
         data={bookmarks}
         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
         renderItem={renderItem}
         showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
         />
    </View>
    );
  }
```

**renderItem**

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("Screen2", {name: item.name})}
        >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flex: 1 }}>
              <View>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 22,
                    paddingRight: 16,
                    color: "black",
                    fontFamily: "Medium",
                    left: 45,
                    top: 6,
                  }}
                >
                  {item.country}
                </Text>
              </View>
              </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you forgot to access props that's the reason booked-marked not working i change some code please check it's working or not.

**StackNavigator.tsx**

```
const RenderItem = (item) => {

    const ifExists = (book) => {
      if (bookmarks.filter((item) => item.id === book.id).length > 0) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    };
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          ifExists(item) ? handleRemoveBookmark(item) : handleAddBookmark(item)
        }
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        style={{
          flexDirection: "row",
          padding: 2,
          backgroundColor: ifExists(i) ? "#F96D41" : "#2D3038",
          borderRadius: 20,
          alignItems: "center",
          justifyContent: "center",
          height: 40,
          width: 40,
        }}
      >
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          color={ifExists(i) ? "white" : "#64676D"}
          size={24}
          name={ifExists(i) ? "bookmark-outline" : "bookmark"}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```